# Database Connection Error DNN 7

Tags: database, connection, dotnetnuke

i am really frustrated from this problem, i am trying to install DNN 7 in windows server 2008, i follwoed the steps in DNN site for installation, but when i run installer wizard i am getting connection error, i give the user permission on Folder level, as owner to the database, and still nothing, do i need to modify the connection in web.config file? is this correct
note:
database name: dnndev.me
user name: Administrator
Password: password

```
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated
Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|dnndev.me.mdf;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

please help
this is my second post and i am not getting answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQLExpress, and you have SQLExpress installed locally using the default instance, you don't need to worry about usernames/passwords for the database. DNN will attach the MDF file in the app_Data folder automatically.

If you are using another INSTANCE of SQL, than you will want to create the Database, and then associate a username/password that is DB_OWNER for that database, and provide that during the installation process. If that is the case, DO NOT choose the SQL Express option, use the SQL 2008 option.

Answer (score 2):

How's  your SqlServer set up? If the server is setup to use integrated security, you really don't need a username/password as Chris pointed out. In that case, the connection string in your web.config `<ConnectionString>` and `<AppSettings>` sections should look like

`Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False;Database=dnndev.me;`

[Check out this blog for more details.](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/1202/DNN-SQLExpress-SQL-Server-Management-Studio.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, This Really helped me as i was editing AppSettings section only and didn't notice the ConnectionStrings Section